# 32-bit Java Accessibility on a 64-bit machine

Tags: c#, java, pinvoke, accessibility

I have a 32-bit app that makes use of Java Accessibility (WindowsAccessBridge-32.dll, via the Java Access Bridge), and works perfectly on a 32-bit machine, but fails on an x64 machine.

I believe I have tracked it down to one of the first calls after Windows_run:

```
getAccessibleContextFromHWND(hwnd, out vmId, out context)
```

defined as follows:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("WindowsAccessBridge-32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static bool getAccessibleContextFromHWND(IntPtr hwnd, out Int32 vmID, out IntPtr acParent);
```

This call works fine on the 32-bit system, returning True, populating both vmId (with some 5-digit value, which), and context - whereas on the 64-bit system, it returns True, populates 'context', but returns '0' for vmId.

If I assume that 0 is valid (even though it's a random 5-digit number resembling a pointer on the 32-bit system), the next call still fails:

```
AccessibleContextInfo aci = new API.AccessibleContextInfo();
if (!getAccessibleContextInfo(vmId, context, ref aci))
  throw new Exception();
```

where:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("WindowsAccessBridge-32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static bool getAccessibleContextInfo(Int32 vmID, IntPtr ac, ref AccessibleContextInfo info);
```

(I'm omitting the AccessibleContextInfo struct for brevity, but I can provide it if necessary).

I know that the libraries are working, because both JavaMonkey and JavaFerret work correctly. Furthermore, call to isJavaWindow works, returning 'true', or 'false' as appropriate, and I am linking to the correct DLL (WindowsAccessBridge-32).

Can anyone suggest what may be wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the problem is in the type of AccessibilityContext:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("WindowsAccessBridge-32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static bool getAccessibleContextFromHWND(IntPtr hwnd, out Int32 vmID, out IntPtr acParent);
```

AccessibilityContext (acParent above), which I had incorrectly mapped as an IntPtr, is actually an Int32 when using the "legacy" WindowsAccessBridge.dll library (used under x86), and an Int64 when using the WOW64 WindowsAccessBridge-32.dll library.

So the upshot is, the code *has* to differ between x86 and WOW x64, and must be compiled separately for each. I do this by #define'ing WOW64 during x64 builds, always referencing the Int64 methods, and using "shim" methods on x86:

```
#if WOW64 // using x64

[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("WindowsAccessBridge-32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static bool getAccessibleContextFromHWND(IntPtr hwnd, out Int32 vmID, out Int64 acParent);

#else // using x86

[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("WindowsAccessBridge.dll", EntryPoint = "getAccessibleContextFromHWND", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private extern static bool _getAccessibleContextFromHWND(IntPtr hwnd, out Int32 vmID, out Int32 acParent);

public static bool getAccessibleContextFromHWND(IntPtr hwnd, out Int32 vmID, out Int64 acParent)
{
  Int32 _acParent;

  bool retVal = _getAccessibleContextFromHWND(hwnd, out vmID, out _acParent);
  acParent = _acParent;

  return retVal;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Every AccessibleContext IntPtr must be replaced by long, including but not limited to getAccessibleContextFromHWND, getAccessibleParentFromContext, getAccessibleChildFromContext, getAccessibleTextInfo...

Answer (score 1):

If your using a 64 bit JVM with a 32 bit version of the Java Access bridge it won't work correctly. You need a 64 bit version of the access bridge which has recently been released. see
http://blogs.oracle.com/korn/entry/java_access_bridge_v2_0
For instructions on installing a 32 bit copy of the access bridge for use with 32 bit JRE's under 64 bit windows see
http://www.travisroth.com/2009/07/03/java-access-bridge-and-64-bit-windows/

Comment: I am using 2.0.2, and have tested both 32-bit and 64-bit JVM's successfully:

64-bit JVM with 32-bit JavaMonkey works
64-bit JVM with 64-bit JavaMonkey works
32-bit JVM with 32-bit JavaMonkey works

So the JavaBridge seems to work fine, from what I can tell, in all instances

Answer (score 1):

The call to 'initializeAccessBridge' REQUIRES you to have an active windows message pump.
Inside 'initializeAccessBridge', it (eventually) creates a hidden dialog window (using CreateDialog). Once the dialog is created, it performs a PostMessage with a registered message. The JavaVM side of the access bridge responds to this message, and posts back another message to the dialog that was created (it appears to be a 'hello' type handshake between your app and the java VM). As such, if your application doesn't have an active message pump, the return message from the JavaVM never gets received by your app.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but note that I already answered my own question ;)

Comment: Sorry, i've been fighting with this myself and this blew my mind when i saw it being as there is no documentation saying this.